# Material-UI useAutocomplete cannot access option in onChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I cannot access the `option.slug` from the object I receive from the API. I am trying to change pass a URL slug and change the route of my app. I am trying to do this using the `onChange` prop inside my `useAutocomplete()` definition.

Accessing the `option.slug` or any other property works well inside of my JSX structure. As you can see I am grabbing `option.title` and so on to render my list items which works well...

Instead of grabbing the actual slug I keep getting the route of "/components/undefined"

But when I try accessing the `option.slug` on the top level of my component in the `useAutocomplete()` definition it doesn't seem to work. Based on the original documentation though, that's the way to do it.

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#useautocomplete

```
export default function NavigationSearch({ onClose, results }) {
    const router = useRouter();

    const {
        getRootProps,
        getInputLabelProps,
        getInputProps,
        getListboxProps,
        getOptionProps,
        groupedOptions
    } = useAutocomplete({
        id: 'use-autocomplete-demo',
        options: results,
        getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title,
        onChange: (option) => router.push(`/components/${option.slug}`)
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {/* 1. SEARCH INPUT */}
            <Container maxWidth="md" disableGutters>
                <Box display="flex" width="100%">
                    <motion.div
                        style={{ width: 'inherit' }}
                        initial="hidden"
                        animate="visible"
                        variants={animation}>
                        <Box display="flex" width="inherit">
                            <Search width="inherit" {...getRootProps()}>
                                <SearchIcon color="primary" />
                                <InputBase
                                    placeholder="Search for components, patterns..."
                                    style={{ color: 'inherit', width: 'inherit' }}
                                    autoFocus
                                    {...getInputProps()}
                                />
                            </Search>
                        </Box>
                    </motion.div>
                    <IconButton color="primary" onClick={onClose}>
                        <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Box>
            </Container>

            {/* SEARCH RESULTS */}
            <BackdropOverlay open={true} onClick={onClose}>
                <Container maxWidth="md" disableGutters>
                    {groupedOptions.length > 0 ? (
                        <Results>
                            <List
                                {...getListboxProps()}
                                subheader={
                                    <Box paddingX={2}>
                                        <Typography
                                            variant="overline"
                                            color="textSecondary"
                                            gutterBottom>
                                            Popular search results
                                        </Typography>
                                    </Box>
                                }>
                                {groupedOptions.map((option, index) => (
                                    <Item
                                        button
                                        key={option.title}
                                        {...getOptionProps({
                                            option,
                                            index
                                        })}>
                                        <Box
                                            display="flex"
                                            justifyContent="space-between"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <Box>
                                                <Typography color="textPrimary">
                                                    {option.title}
                                                </Typography>
                                                <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                                                    {option.type}
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                            <Box alignSelf="flex-end">
                                                <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                                                    /components/button
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Box>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Item>
                                ))}
                            </List>
                        </Results>
                    ) : null}
                </Container>
            </BackdropOverlay>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

This is the API response that I store in the results prop:

```
0: {id: 1, title: "Button", slug: "button"}
1: {id: 2, title: "Switch", slug: "switch"}
2: {id: 3, title: "Tags", slug: "tags"}
3: {id: 4, title: "Checkbox", slug: "checkbox"}
4: {id: 5, title: "Toast", slug: "toast"}
```

Comment: Can you log the value of `results` props in your question?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I added it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Autocomplete` component uses `useAutocomplete` hook under the hood so they share the same API. In `Autocomplete` [API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/). This is the signature of `onChange`:

```js
function(event: object, value: T | T[], reason: string) => void
```

The second argument is the option value which is what you need here. So change your code to:

```js
onChange: (_, option) => router.push(`/components/${option.slug}`)
```

To fix the `undefined` value issue.

Comment: thanks. ignoring the first arguement saved my back "(_, option)"

Comment: @AlainIb you can print the argument list to learn about them like this: `(...args) => console.log(args)`.